# Problem with Jquery in django project template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm facing a problem in this Django project where I'm working to get a dynamic dependent drop-down.

This part of the script is not sending any Ajax request.
As a beginner, I'm trying to do random projects.
I didn't know more about Ajax and Javascript.
Is there any problem in this code?

[image]

Comment: So in my understanding, your server doesn't get any requests? Can you debug if you actually enter the function handler, if you do, check  `URL` and `districtId`  consts are as expected?

Comment: In addition, the default method/type of the request is `GET` seeing you have some data you need to use a `POST` request. Check out the ajax documentation https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ok ,Let me go through the documentation.Hope it works!     Also, I wonder why this script part is all white colored and not like having some highlighted fn parts as it is seen elsewhere.

Comment: Hey, thank you for sharing your code. But it would be appreciated if you could please insert the code as formatted text, not as screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.